# ERROR 404 WHEN I TRY THIS LINK http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jboss, swagger, custom-error-pages

Im trying to document my spring boot proyect, but when i enter the link http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, the page is white and there is only a 404 error. Im using java 8 and spring boot 2.7.0 and jboss 7.2 .these are my configurations

```
type here
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

package com.example.springbootdemo.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    public static final Contact DEFAULT_CONTACT = new Contact(
            "Sample App", "http://www.sample.com", "sample@gmail.com");

    public static final ApiInfo DEFAULT_API_INFO = new ApiInfo(
            "Awesome API Title", "Awesome API Description", "1.0",
            "urn:tos", DEFAULT_CONTACT,
            "Apache 2.0", "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0", Arrays.asList());

    private static final Set<String> DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES =
            new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("application/json",
                    "application/xml"));

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(DEFAULT_API_INFO)
                .produces(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES)
                .consumes(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES);
    }
}
```

Iv tried using many versions of spring fox, open api and spring ui, but none of them worked, and I used various differents configurations in the Swagger Configuration